# Oracle 19 Error on docker run with data volume mounted

Tags: oracle, docker, docker-volume, oracle19c

I have build an Oracle Database 19 docker image (tagged as oracle:19) as described in the oracle official documentation
https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/main/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance.

Then I run it using a docker-compose among other services :

```
oracle:
    image: oracle:19
    ports:
      - "1521:1521"
      - "5500:5500"
    environment:
      ORACLE_SID: MY_SID
      ORACLE_PWD: MY_STRONG_PASSWORD
      ORACLE_EDITION: ee
      ORACLE_PDB: MY_SERVICE_NAME
    volumes:
      - .\ora19data:/opt/oracle/oradata
```

The database started well, then I created my schema, tablespaces, tables ... etc then I did some test inserts.
When I shut down the database and start it again, I get this **beautiful error** :

```
oracle-19_1  | SQL> ORACLE instance started.
oracle-19_1  |
oracle-19_1  | Total System Global Area 1610610568 bytes
oracle-19_1  | Fixed Size                   9136008 bytes
oracle-19_1  | Variable Size              486539264 bytes
oracle-19_1  | Database Buffers  1107296256 bytes
oracle-19_1  | Redo Buffers                 7639040 bytes
oracle-19_1  | Database mounted.
oracle-19_1  | ORA-01157: cannot identify/lock data file 13 - see DBWR trace file
oracle-19_1  | ORA-01110: data file 13: '/home/oracle/d_XXX01_01.dbf'
oracle-19_1  |
oracle-19_1  |
oracle-19_1  | SQL> Disconnected from Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
oracle-19_1  | Version 19.3.0.0.0
oracle-19_1  | The Oracle base remains unchanged with value /opt/oracle
oracle-19_1  | #####################################
oracle-19_1  | ########### E R R O R ###############
oracle-19_1  | DATABASE SETUP WAS NOT SUCCESSFUL!
oracle-19_1  | Please check output for further info!
oracle-19_1  | ########### E R R O R ###############
oracle-19_1  | #####################################
oracle-19_1  | The following output is now a tail of the alert.log:
oracle-19_1  | Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
oracle-19_1  | Additional information: 7
oracle-19_1  | 2021-03-21T20:38:52.212817+00:00
oracle-19_1  | Errors in file /opt/oracle/diag/rdbms/XXX/trace/XXXXXX_mz00_121.trc:
oracle-19_1  | ORA-01110: data file 14: '/home/oracle/i_XXX01_01.dbf'
oracle-19_1  | ORA-01565: error in identifying file '/home/oracle/i_XXX01_01.dbf'
oracle-19_1  | ORA-27037: unable to obtain file status
oracle-19_1  | Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
oracle-19_1  | Additional information: 7
oracle-19_1  | Checker run found 2 new persistent data failures
```

Already tried to google errors and the 5 ORA-XXX, but in vain !

Comment: Make sure you have set permissions on the database volume directory. Please have a look at my compose file: https://github.com/bjarteb/oracle-apex-ords/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

Comment: Thanks @BjarteBrandt, in fact I am using Docker Desktop for Windows 10 and I read in some articles that either the user oracle (54321) should be the owner of volume or the volume should be writable by everyone (777), I tried using WSL Ubuntu to try this but none of the two solutions worked !